# Feature Selection in Twitter Sentiment Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently working on a twitter sentiment analysis project. In this project, one requirement is to perform Feature selection for a better prediction. But I'm fairly confused about the techniques to do feature selection:

I assumed that removing stopwords, @mentions, punctuation etc. are all steps for the pre-processing of the tweets. Now I discussed that matter with a group member and I was told that those steps are already part of the feature selection. And on top of that, there are also statistical methods to select the features even more.

Now I wanted to make sure if that's true because then I'm not sure what exactly belongs to the pre-processing?

I'm grateful for every input :)

Answer (score 0):

**Feature selection** is a well-studied area within Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition. In general, pruning features is a *non-monotonous* process. The relative importance of remaining features change when seemingly redundant features are being removed from your Twitter sentiment classifier.

There are ready-to-use webservices available that perform feature selection for you, complete with a graphical analysis and feature ranking. Take a look at [classifier service](https://insight-classifiers.com/wos), which has an option for feature selection and feature analysis.

Just adding (almost) indefinitely many feature variables to a classifier leads to so-called **peaking**, which means that after a certain point adding even more feature variables begins to *reduce* the performance on independent test sets. This reduction in performance is counter intuitive because all the truly informative variables are still presented to the classifier. The performance **peak** has been exceeded. *Peaking* is caused by over-generalization because each added feature introduces yet more parameters to the classifier. At a certain point, ***given a limited training set size***, the parameters begin to fit noise in the data.

Advanced feature-selection schemes are available including floating search and Markov chain Monte Carlo techniques. Applying these algorithms to feature selection requires specialist knowledge.